# Failed to add a node to spatial layer with https post request in Neo4j php

Tags: php, curl, neo4j, http-post

I'm trying to add a node to the index spatial.

```
 $path = '/db/data/index/node/'.$layer;
    $nodePath = DbConfig::getFullDatabaseServerUrl() . '/db/data/node/' . $nodeId;
    $data = array("key" => "dummy", "value" => "dummy","uri"=>$nodePath);
    $data =json_encode($data);
    DbRestManager::send($path,$data);


public  static function send($path, $data) {
        $url = DbConfig::getFullDatabaseServerUrl() . $path;
        $auth=DbConfig::getUserName().':'.DbConfig::getPassword();
        $authEcoded=base64_encode($auth);

        $headers = array('Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8','Authorization: Basic '.$authEcoded,'Content-Type: application/json');

        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);

    }
```

> $data={"key":"dummy","value":"dummy","uri":"dev_db.pico-app.com:7473/db/data/node/11"}

Everything seems fine, but the operation doesn't work.For some reason i also can't see error.

Answer (score 0):

From the [spatial server documentation](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/spatial/#spatial-server-plugin), adding node to an index has a complete different json payload to send, and to a different endpoint.

You'll have first to create a spatial layer, then create a spatial index and then only add your node to the spatial index.

```
Example request

POST http://localhost:7575/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addNodeToLayer

Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8

Content-Type: application/json

{
  "layer" : "geom",
  "node" : "http://localhost:7575/db/data/node/54"
}
```

Instead of using curl in raw, you may want to use [neoclient](https://github.com/neoxygen/neo4j-neoclient) and the [spatial extension](https://github.com/neoxygen/neoclient-spatial-extension) for it that will remove you all the burden of the http requests and provide useful methdods, a simple example:

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php');

use Neoxygen\NeoClient\ClientBuilder;

$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->addConnection('default', 'https', 'localhost', 7474, true, 'neo4j', 'password')
    ->setAutoFormatResponse(true)
    ->registerExtension('spatial', 'Neoxygen\\NeoClientExtension\\Spatial\\SpatialExtension')
    ->build();


$client->createSpatialIndex();
$client->createSimplePointLayer();
// Create first some nodes with lat and lon values
// Retrieve them and add them to the spatial index
$q = $client->sendCypherQuery('MATCH (n:Step) RETURN n');
$steps = $q->getResult()->getNodes();
foreach ($steps as $step) {
    $client->addNodeToSpatialIndex($step->getId());
}
```